# Create new Single Object from an ArrayObject

Tags: angularjs, json, object, underscore.js, lodash

I want an `Object` which I can simply change to **JSON** format for Exporting later on.
For this I have an `array` of `objects` like this:

```
[
  {
    "name": "Test",
    "value": "EN Test"
  },
  {
    "name": "Test2",
    "value": "DE test2"
  }
]
```

It has to be exact like this

```
{
 "Test" : "EN Test",
 "Test2" : "DE test2",
}
```

So a Single Object with the Value of all Objects of the Array but only the Values of '`name`' and '`value`'.
Angular merge/copy/extend and so on is working with 2 Arrays and just merging them without Options like get only value of name and value.
With `Lodash`

```
object = _.map(objectArray,'name');
Giving me
[ "Test", "Test2", ]
But with multiple
object = _.map(objectArray,['name','value']);
[ false, false, ]
doing
object = _.map(objectarray,_.partial(_.ary(_.pick,2),_,['name','value']));
output is
[ { "name": "Test", "value": "EN Test" }, { "name": "Test2", "value": "DE test2" } ]
not
{ "Test" : "EN Test", "Test2" : "DE test2", }
```

and so on

```
object = _.mapValues(objectArray,'name');
{
  "0": "Test",
  "1": "Values",
}
this.lang = _.mapValues(this.exportData,_.partial(_.ary(_.pick,2),_,['name','value']));

  "0": {
    "name": "Test",
    "value": "Test"
  },
  "1": {
    "name": "TEst2",
    "value": "Test2"
  },..
```

What can I do to achieve is

```
{
 "Test" : "EN Test",
 "Test2" : "DE test2",
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```js
var a = [
      {
        "name": "Test",
        "value": "EN Test"
      },
      {
        "name": "Test2",
        "value": "DE test2"
      }
    ];

    var obj = {};

    a.forEach(function(node){
        obj[node.name] = node.value
    });

    console.log(obj);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use native JavaScript **[`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)** method.

```js
var data = [{
  "name": "Test",
  "value": "EN Test"
}, {
  "name": "Test2",
  "value": "DE test2"
}];

// iterate over array
var res = data.reduce(function(obj, v) {
  // define the object property
  obj[v.name] = v.value;
  // return the object
  return obj;
  // define initial value as empty object
  // for storing the result
}, {})

console.log(res);
```